# SwiftUI NavigationLink becomes activate when button is clicked but deactivate immediately

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am using swiftui with firebase (backend). I am trying to redirect user to other screen (photo screen) when the Sign up button is clicked . I am expecting when user click the sign up button with the information it will store the data into database(firebase) and show the photo screen and stay on that screen. But the problem is when I clicked the button , it navigate to photo screen but Immediately it move to sign up screen again. I am using navigation link with destination ,isActive and label. I also used boolean property to set it true when the NavigationLink becomes active and it is published property.

Here is my @main view code ..

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct Twitter_Demo_YoutubeApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for content view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showManu = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            // no user logged in
            if viewModel.userSession == nil {
                LoginView()
                
            } else {
                // have a logged in user.
                mainInterfaceView
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

extension ContentView {
    
    var mainInterfaceView: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            MainTabView()
                .navigationBarHidden(showManu)
            
            if showManu {
                ZStack {
                    Color(.black)
                        .opacity(showManu ? 0.25: 0.0)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        showManu = false
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            
            SideManuView()
                .frame(width: 300)
                .offset(x: showManu ? 0 : -300, y: 0)
                .background(showManu ? Color.white : Color.clear)
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Home")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        showManu.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            showManu = false
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my view model code.

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var didAuthenciateUser = false
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser        
    }
func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String, username: String) {
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
                      
            let data = [
                "email": email,
                "username": username.lowercased(),
                "fullname": fullname,
                "uid": user.uid]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data) { _ in
                    self.didAuthenciateUser = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Registration view..

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var fullname = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: ProfilePhotoSelecterView(),
                           isActive: $viewModel.didAuthenciateUser, 
                           label: { }) // here is the NavigationLink to be active                              
            
            AuthHeaderView(title1: "Get started.", title2: "Create your account")
            
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                CustomInputField(imageName: "envelope",
                                 placeholderText: "Email",
                                 text: $email)
                 
                 CustomInputField(imageName: "person",
                                  placeholderText: "username",
                                  text: $username)
                
                CustomInputField(imageName: "person",
                                 placeholderText: "Full Name",
                                 text: $fullname)
                 
                 CustomInputField(imageName: "lock",
                                  placeholderText: "Password",
                                  isSecureField: true,
                                  text: $password)
                
            }
            .padding(32)
            
            Button {
                viewModel.register(withEmail: email,
                                   password: password,
                                   fullname: fullname,
                                   username: username)
            } label: {
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding()
            }
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Already have account?")
                        .font(.footnote)
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 32)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

#Preview {
    RegistrationView()
}
```

Here is the destination view code(ProfilePhotoSelecterView) ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfilePhotoSelecterView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            AuthHeaderView(title1: "Create your account.", 
                           title2: "Add a profile a photo")
            
            Button {
               print("Pick image here..")
            } label: {
                Image("addphoto")
                    .resizable()
                   // .renderingMode(.template)
                   // .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBlue))
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 180, height: 180)
                    .padding(.top, 44)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ProfilePhotoSelecterView()
}
```

Here is the screenshot ..
[image: Initial screen]

here is the screenshot when the sign up button is clicked but it redirect with sign up screen automatically .

[image: photo screen]

Here is the sign up screen.
[image]

Comment: What happens in ContentView ?

Comment: one minute please let me add the code for content view as well .

Comment: in the content view I am checking show the view based user is logged in or not

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 16+, consider using `NavigationStack`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: Correct we can use that property but I want understand why the current logic is not working . if we use the old property like NavigationLink it will give us warning

Comment: Is RegistrationView the LoginView ?

Comment: As soon as you register the test (viewModel.userSession == nil) become false, which trigger a redraw of ContentView. Pay attention that updating your view moddl updates it in ALL views.

Comment: yes . this where I am trying to find out . I have set up target version to 17.1 but it looks it conflicting with NavigationLink

Answer (score 0):

Can you use toggle `self.didAuthenciateUser.toggle()`, instead of `self.didAuthenciateUser = true` ?

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
                      
            let data = [
                "email": email,
                "username": username.lowercased(),
                "fullname": fullname,
                "uid": user.uid]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data) { _ in
                    self.didAuthenciateUser.toggle()
            }
        }
```

Comment: it the same response and result . It already making it true on registration function . toggle does the same stuff